# Rails 4: order association on count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a model `Post` and a model `Comment`. `Post` stands in a `has_many` relationship to `Comment`. `Post` should order by count of `Comment`. I would not use counter cache for this. How should my scope be?

THX

Comment: Good question. I am not sure, with my answer. So deleted, I am not able to test it now. :-(

Comment: Why do you want `scope`? As an alternative,you can do this with below `AR query` `Post.includes(:comments).group("comments.post_id").order("count(comments.post_id) desc")`

Comment: @Pavan I need a scope for the Filterrific Gem http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/active_record_scope_patterns.html#sort